# SQL query to find multi level hierarchical data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine I have some data in a relational table like below.

```
name           friend_name 

Ryan           James 
Chin           James 
Jack           Charley
Tomy           Ryan
Bill           Chin
```

Now, given friend_name 'James' I want the result as

```
name 

Ryan 
Chin 
Tomy
Bill
```

What should my SQL query look like? I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Please note that 'Jame' is actually 'James' in the row where his friend_name is Dinand

Comment: How is this hierarchical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to find all the friends of friends of `James`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM friends
  WHERE friend_name = 'James'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.*
  FROM friends f
  JOIN CTE ON f.friend_name = CTE.name
)
SELECT name
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
name
Ryan
Chin
Bill
Tomy
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f14b5/1)

Answer (score 0):

The entry level way to do this would just be a `UNION` if you don't have duplicates.

```
SELECT name
FROM t1
WHERE friend_name = 'James'

UNION

SELECT friend_name name
FROM t2
WHERE name = 'James'
```